# circle around a city in R with a given radius and transparency dependent on sales amount

Tags: r, dictionary, transparency

I need some advice(s) on how can I draw a `circle` around a `city` on a `map` (so I will need to add a world map first) in `R`, with the below two things to match:

1. the circle of the radius is given, let's say 10kms
2. the circle is filled with some color, say green
3. the transparency of the color of the circle is dependent on the sales for the given city. More the sales darker the shade and vice versa.

Comment: Could you show us your effort and what you have done so far? Here are [some tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) about posting a reproducible answer. This set apart, ggmap package + geom_point(aes(size...)) may help